# Why isn't my .gitignore ignoring a folder?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitignore

Using GitLab, need to hide the folder `.vscode`.

I copied the template from here: https://gist.github.com/takekazuomi/10955889

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

...

Task1/Task1/.vscode

...
```

Images of:

[Project File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xGKr.png)

[GitLab Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALPmi.png)

Comment: If you already had the files in the folder committed and pushed, before you added the folder in .gitignore, it will not have any effect. .gitignore applies only to not committed files.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your relative path to your .vscode folder is really correct - alternatively you can exclude all .vscode folders by adding `*.vscode` to your `.gitignore`.

Have you already committed and pushed to your Gitlab repository? The file-structures between your local and remote project seem to be different.